# hasnextdouble not reading my next double in a file

Tags: java, oop, file-handling

Hi I'm having trouble with the scanner method `hasNextDouble()`.
My code reads from a file and creates a `Vehicle` object, to be added to an array. The vehicle class has a subclass called `OversizedVehicle`, with an additional `double` field to indicate its height. Which is why I am using the `if (hasNextDouble())` so if the scanner reads a `double` it would create an `OversizedVehicle` object instead of `Vehicle`. Here's my code:

```
while(s1.hasNext()) 
    {
            regNo = s1.next();
            make = s1.next();
            year = Integer.parseInt(s1.next());
            description = s1.next();
            if(s1.hasNextDouble() == true) {
            height = s1.nextDouble();
            vehicle = new OversizedVehicle(regNo,make,year,description,height);
            }
            else {
            vehicle = new Vehicle(regNo, make, year, description);
            }
            System.out.println("New vehicles from file added to array in position " + count);
            vehicles[count] = vehicle;
            count++;
    }
```

I am using the Eclipse IDE and when I run this in debug mode the `if` statement always evaluates to `true`, incorrectly putting the next `regNo` in the input into the `height` variable. Even though in the input this value is not a `double`, but an `int`. I am not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: What's your input file look like?

Comment: Please capitalize and punctuate and paragraph this unintelligible mess, and define '`hasNextDouble()` not reading my next double.' What happens instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me your input contains parameters of *vehicles* and *oversized vehicles*, where their number of parameters are different: vehicles have 4 parameters, oversized vehicles have 5, something like this:

> ```
> 1 Toyota 2015 sedan 2 Toyota 2016 truck 2.1 3 Toyota 2015 mini ...
> ```

And so on. I am guessing this because you seem to say that `s1.hasNextDouble()` is always true,
and it causes *"the variable regNo to be initialised into a double"*.
This could happen for example when the scanner has read "sedan" in the example above,
the next token is "2",
and since "2" can be a valid `double`,
`s1.hasNextDouble()` returns true.
In other words, `s1.hasNextDouble()` will be true when the next token is a double or an integer.

You could distinguish these cases by checking for `s1.hasNextInt()`,
because that will return `false` for a `double` and `true` for an `int`.

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
  String regNo = scanner.next();
  String make = scanner.next();
  int year = scanner.nextInt();
  String description = scanner.next();

  if (scanner.hasNext() && !scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    double height = scanner.nextDouble();
    vehicle = new OversizedVehicle(regNo, make, year, description, height);
  } else {
    vehicle = new Vehicle(regNo, make, year, description);
  }

  // ...
}
```

This should work for the example above.
But if your data is line-by-line,
then I would recommend to rely on the line separator to distinguish the records,
it will make the implementation a bit simpler and clearer.

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
  String line = scanner.nextLine();
  String[] parts = line.split(" ");
  String regNo = parts[0];
  String make = parts[1];
  int year = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
  String description = parts[3];

  if (parts.length == 5) {
    double height = scanner.nextDouble();
    vehicle = new OversizedVehicle(regNo, make, year, description, height);
  } else {
    vehicle = new Vehicle(regNo, make, year, description);
  }

  // ...
}
```